# How to check if the user has entered the value of date or not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I am trying to develop a system which checks if the date is entered by the user or not, however when ever i try to use these `if(!date){//code}` or  `if(date.length==0)` i don't get what i want, maybe because `<input type="date">` execute input feild with **dd-----yyyy** and a **celender** in the browser which is counted as a value in js.

So my question is to get 1 if the date is entered by the user and 0 if user leaves the field empty or default ( **dd-----yyyy** and a **celender** ).

[image: How look in browser.]

Comment: It should be `date.value` if `date` is the input element.

Comment: pls show the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have To Use

```
if(date.value.length == 0)
```

Not

```
if(date.length==0)
```

```js
var f = document.querySelector("form");
f.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  var d = document.getElementById("date");
  if(d.value.length < 1){
    alert("Date Is Required");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Or Try This way

```js
var f = document.querySelector("form");
f.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  const d = document.getElementById("date");
  if(!d.checkValidity()){
    alert("Date Is Required");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form novalidate>
      <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required>
      <button>Go</button>
    </form>
```